# Subdomain to subfolder in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-vhost-alias

I am looking for Apache configuration that would allow for the following:

- Serve *sub.domain.com* as `/%docRoot%/domain.com/sub`, and
- Would be able to do this **for every hosted domain and any subdomain** (ie. no per-domain vhost configuration)

I would be grateful for any solution, especially if there was no `mod_rewrite` involved (using `mod_vhost_alias`).

Note: There are some obvious solutions using `mod_vhost_alias`, but they either work for *domain.com* or *sub.domain.com*, none of them seems to cover both cases.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point `*.domain.com` to your document root (`/%docRoot%/`). You'll need to do this in a vhost config. In that same vhost, add this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain.com/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /domain.com/%1/$1 [L]
```

If you want to avoid pointing `www.domain.com` to `/%docRoot%/domain.com/www`, then add a condition to exclude it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain.com/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /domain.com/%1/$1 [L]
```

---

EDIT:

> I assume I will still have to do this for every hosted domain (as the examples you've posted all refer to "domain.com"). Am I right?

Yes, the above will only do the routing for `domain.com`, if you want to do this for all arbitrary `domain.com`, you'll need to do something a bit more tricky:

```
RewriteEngine On
# here, %1 = subdomain name, and %2 = domain name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.(.+)$ [NC]
# make sure the request doesn't already start with the domain name/subdomain name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%2/%1 !^/([^/]+/[^/]+)[^:]*:\1
# rewrite
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /%2/%1/$1 [L]
```

The tricky thing here is the `%{REQUEST_URI}:%2/%1 !^/([^/]+/[^/]+)[^:]*:\1` match. It posits the condition: `%{REQUEST_URI}:domain.com/sub` and makes sure the `%{REQUEST_URI}` *doesn't start with* the `domain.com/sub` (back refrenced from previous match using %2/%1) using the `\1` back reference.

With this, you setup your vhost to accept *every domain* (default vhost) and any subdomain/domain will get routed. Examples:

- `http://blah.bleh.org/file.txt` goes to `/%docRoot%/bleh.org/blah/file.txt`
- `http://foo.bar.com/some/path/` goes to `/%docRoot%/bar.com/foo/some/path/`
- `http://sub2.sub1.d.com/index.html` goes to `/%docRoot%/sub1.d.com/sub2/index.html`

---

EDIT2:

> Yes, I would very much like to get domain.com routed to `/%docRoot%/domain.com/`

Try these:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%2/%1 !^/([^/]+/[^/]+)[^:]*:\1
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /%2/%1/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%1 !^/([^/]+)[^:]*:\1
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

Basically the same thing, except a few of the regex needs to be tweaked to separate what a `domain.com` is like vs `sub.domain.com`. If you want to redirect `www.domain.com` to `domain.com`, that needs to happen *before* these rules.

Comment: I assume I will still have to do this for every hosted domain (as the examples you've posted all refer to "domain.com"). Am I right?

Comment: @David If you want it for any arbitrary "domain.com" as well, it'll get a little more tricky, see edit

Comment: Jon, I will try to understand the solution, see if it works for me and post you back. Thank you for the help so far!

Comment: First, everything up to the first dot (.) will be accessible as `%1` and `%2` will stand for the rest.

Second, in the "tricky bit", I make sure *not to route what has already been routed* (to avoid infinite loops). Weird! It works without it as well.

Third, I rewrite. Little problem here, though: domain.com will route to `%docRoot%/com/domain`.

Jon, would you patiently explain to me why the config works w/o the mentioned part as well? And, would you please head me in the right direction with the "non-subdomain" rewrite?

Comment: @David No idea how removing that still works for you. In a blank htaccess file on a test apache install, it internally loops and I get a 500 error without it. As for the second question, where should a `domain.com` get rewritten to? Just `/%docRoot%/domain.com/`?

Comment: Huh, strange. Will try to find that out on my own, don't worry about that. Yes, I would very much like to get *domain.com* routed to `/%docRoot%/domain.com/` (I will use .htaccess to do a "domain.com" -> "www.domain.com" redirect where appropriate.).

Comment: Jon, **thank you very much** for your help. I have been trying hard to find the solution myself somewhere for hours, you gave it in a minute. Have a nice day!